# How to modify a title Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, padding, title, radar-chart

How could I edit the second row of my title to be a smaller font and normal weight? Also, how could I adjust the padding between the title and the plot?

If you have any other comments on how to make this plot look better, I'd definitely appreciate your comments and expertise.

Here is an image of my plot and the code to go with it.

[image: Current Plot Image]

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.pyplot as py

class Radar(object):

def __init__(self, fig, titles, labels, rect=None):
    if rect is None:
        rect = [0.05, 0.05, 0.95, 0.95]

    self.n = len(titles)
    self.angles = [a if a <=360. else a - 360. for a in np.arange(90, 90+360, 360.0/self.n)]
    self.axes = [fig.add_axes(rect, projection="polar", label="axes%d" % i) 
                     for i in range(self.n)]

    self.ax = self.axes[0]
    self.ax.set_thetagrids(self.angles, labels=titles, fontsize=12, weight="bold", color="black")

    for ax in self.axes[1:]:
        ax.patch.set_visible(False)
        ax.grid("off")
        ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
        self.ax.yaxis.grid(False)

    for ax, angle, label in zip(self.axes, self.angles, labels):
        ax.set_rgrids(range(1, 7), labels=label, angle=angle, fontsize=12)
        ax.spines["polar"].set_visible(False)
        ax.set_ylim(0, 6)  
        ax.xaxis.grid(True,color='black',linestyle='-')
        pos=ax.get_rlabel_position()
        ax.set_rlabel_position(pos+3)

def plot(self, values, *args, **kw):
    angle = np.deg2rad(np.r_[self.angles, self.angles[0]])
    values = np.r_[values, values[0]]
    self.ax.plot(angle, values, *args, **kw)

fig = pl.figure(figsize=(20, 20))

titles = [
"Canada", "Australia", "New\nZealand", "Japan", "China", "USA", "Mexico", "Finland", "Doha" 
]

labels = [
list("abcde"), list("12345"), list("uvwxy"), 
[" ", " ", "$156", "$158", "$160"],
list("jklmn"), list("asdfg"), list("qwert"), [" ", "4.3", "4.4", "4.5", "4.6"], list("abcde")
]

radar = Radar(fig, titles, labels)
radar.plot([1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 5, 3, 3, 2],  "--", lw=1, color="b", alpha=.5, label="USA 2014")
radar.plot([2.3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2],"-", lw=1, color="r", alpha=.5, label="2014")
radar.plot([3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2], "-", lw=1, color="g", alpha=.5, label="2013")
radar.plot([4.5, 5, 4, 5, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2], "-", lw=1, color="y", alpha=.5, label="2012")

radar.ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.10),
      fancybox=True, shadow=True, ncol=4)

py.title("Seattle, WA\nData from 2012 to 2014", weight="bold", fontsize=14)

fig = py.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(6, 10, forward=True)
fig.savefig('test2png.png', dpi=100, bbox_inches="tight", pad_inches=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot have two different weights/font sizes within a single text object. But what you can do is add a new text object with a different weight.

I replaced the `title` call in your script with this:

```
py.text(0.5, 1.1, "Seattle, WA\n", weight="bold", fontsize=14,
        transform=py.gca().transAxes, ha='center')
py.text(0.5, 1.1, "Data from 2012 to 2014",
        transform=py.gca().transAxes, ha='center')
```

The result, I think, is something like what you were hoping for:

[image]